# TFS online Publish artifact

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am very new to DevOps. I have a WebAPI project, and i am using TFS Online Services for my version control. I am able to check-in my code and enabled the "CI", so whenever I check-in my code TFS runs a build and alerts me via email.

My next challenge is, take the output of the BUILD and publish it to my "FTP Server". **I have no idea where exactly TFS is droping the "Build Content" by default**. I have no idea how to setup the "**Publish artifact**" Task. please guide me how to set this up.

Comment: Did you start by reading the documentation?

Comment: yes, did not help at all.

Comment: @DanielMann someone answered my question below in such a nicer way, why you had to act so tough? someone who never used TFS before and it was a very simply question. off course i did my research before asking the question.

Comment: Many people who ask questions similar to this **did not** read the documentation, so asking if you've read it is a reasonable starting point. If you don't want to be asked if you read the documentation, you could mention that you did and point out what in the documentation was unclear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> TFS online Publish artifact

If you publish the output of build to the FTP Server, you could try to use [FTP Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/ftp-upload?view=azure-devops) task instead of [Publish Build Artifacts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/publish-build-artifacts?view=azure-devops) task.

**Publish Build Artifacts task:** Use this task in a build pipeline to publish build artifacts to Azure Pipelines, TFS, or a file share.

**FTP Upload task:** Use this task in a build or release pipeline to upload files to a remote machine using the File Transfer Protocol (FTP), or securely with FTPS.

Besides, before we use the `Publish Build Artifacts`/`FTP Upload task` task, we should use a [Copy Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/copy-files?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) task to copy the output of build to the Artifact, the Artifact Staging Directory folder is the default folder where TFS droping：

[image]

Check following document for some more details:

[FTP deployed from Azure Devops](https://martincarlsen.com/ftp-deploy-from-vsts/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much, "Artifact Staging Directory folder", where is it pointing to? how do i find the "Physical Path" of this directory?

Comment: @user2404597, It points to the Artifacts folder on the agent, like C:\<agentNAame>\_work\5\a\, you can see it in your build's log.